# Array reversed when it's sent using the form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, foreach

I'm sending 3 arrays with checkboxes (checked and not) using a form to a PHP page, trying to do an Insert in a MySQL database. When I send an array with length = 1, it inserts just fine, but arrays with length superior to 1 are shown (and insert) reversed when 2 or 3 checkboxes are checked, occupying index 0 of the array, being that it was at index 1 at first.

I'm using WAMP 3.1.7 64 bits, PHP 7.2.14 and Brackets. The arrays are called "electricidad", "proyector" and "wifi". I create the checkboxes with a button using the function nuevaSala (element), function checkboxElegido() is to change the value of checked checkboxes (no is the default).

```
<script>
        var instancia = 0;

        function nuevaSala(element){
            instancia++;

            var newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
            newDiv.name = "nuevasSalasDiv[]";
            newDiv.id = "nuevasSalas"+instancia;

            var newLabel = document.createElement("LABEL");
            newLabel.id = "Sala"+instancia;
            newLabel.innerHTML = "Sala "+instancia;

            var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            newInput.id = "sala"+instancia;
            newInput.name = "nombreSala[]";
            newInput.type = "text";

            var newLabel1 = document.createElement("LABEL");
            newLabel1.id = "Capacidad"+instancia;
            newLabel1.innerHTML = "Capacidad";

            var newInput1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
            newInput1.id = "capacidad"+instancia;
            newInput1.name = "capacidad[]";
            newInput1.type = "number";

            var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
            newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
            newCheckbox.name = "electricidad[]";
            newCheckbox.id = "electricidad"+instancia;
            newCheckbox.value = "no";
            newCheckbox.setAttribute("onclick", "checkboxElegido()");            
            newCheckbox.setAttribute("style", "float: right");

            var newCheckbox1 = document.createElement("input");
            newCheckbox1.type = "checkbox";
            newCheckbox1.name = "wifi[]";
            newCheckbox1.id = "wifi"+instancia;
            newCheckbox1.value = "no";
            newCheckbox1.setAttribute("onclick", "checkboxElegido()");
            newCheckbox1.setAttribute("style", "float: right");

            var newCheckbox2 = document.createElement("input");
            newCheckbox2.type = "checkbox";
            newCheckbox2.name = "proyector[]";
            newCheckbox2.id = "proyector"+instancia;
            newCheckbox2.value = "no";
            newCheckbox2.setAttribute("onclick", "checkboxElegido()");
            newCheckbox2.setAttribute("style", "float: right");

            var newLabelElec = document.createElement("LABEL");
            newLabelElec.innerHTML = "Electricidad";
            newLabelElec.setAttribute("style", "float: right");
            var newLabelProy = document.createElement("LABEL");
            newLabelProy.innerHTML = "Proyector";
            newLabelProy.setAttribute("style", "float: right");
            var newLabelWifi = document.createElement("LABEL");
            newLabelWifi.innerHTML = "Wifi";
            newLabelWifi.setAttribute("style", "float: right");

            document.getElementById("salaId").appendChild(newDiv);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newLabel);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newInput);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newLabel1);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newInput1);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newLabelElec);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newCheckbox);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newLabelProy);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newCheckbox2);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newLabelWifi);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(newCheckbox1);
            document.getElementById("nuevasSalas"+instancia).appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));

        }

    </script>
```

```
<script>

        function checkboxElegido(){
            var proy = document.getElementsByName("proyector[]");

            var wifi = document.getElementsByName("wifi[]");

            var elec = document.getElementsByName("electricidad[]");


            function valores(item){
                if(item.checked){
                    item.setAttribute("value", "si");    
                } else if(!item.checked){
                    item.setAttribute("value", "no");
                }

            }

            proy.forEach(valores);
            wifi.forEach(valores);
            elec.forEach(valores);

        }

    </script>
```

If the array has lenght 2, and the checked checkbox is "electricidad" in index 0 and checked in index 1 are "wifi", "electricidad" and "proyector", I expect this:

[0] = "electricidad" => si, "wifi" => no, "proyector" => no

[1] = "electricidad" => si, "wifi" => si, "proyector" => si

but I got this:

[0] = "electricidad" => si, "wifi" => si, "proyector" => si

[1] = "electricidad" => si

Beforehand, thank you!

Comment: Please fix your code, add some space and new line, also format the source code using available tag.

Comment: Checkboxes only become part of the form submission data set, if they are actuallyy checked. Setting the value to “no” doesn’t change anything about that - it will not be submitted, unless the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for clearing it ;)